# Roboguice together with Sherlock?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, roboguice

I'm trying to use Roboguice with Sherlock. But even cannot start my Testapp when extending `RoboSherlockFragmentActivity`

Do I have to take anything into account which I might have missed?

```
06-06 10:23:59.700: I/dalvikvm(917): Failed resolving Lcom/github/rtyley/android/sherlock/roboguice/activity/RoboSherlockFragmentActivity; interface 1352 'Lroboguice/util/RoboContext;'
06-06 10:23:59.700: W/dalvikvm(917): Link of class 'Lcom/github/rtyley/android/sherlock/roboguice/activity/RoboSherlockFragmentActivity;' failed
```

Comment: Usually this kind of errors are caused by dependency mismatch. You're importing older/newer version of library than required by dependent library.

Comment: may i know which version of roboguice you are using

Comment: roboguice 2 and roboguice-sherlock 1.4, which should both be latest

Comment: are you using maven to manage these dependencies?